# Fetching API data on localhost with VueJS

Tags: vue.js, xampp, vuejs2, localhost, vue-resource

So this is my function, really simple:

```
mounted: function(){
      this.$http.get('http://localhost:80/gaming/api/game/1').then((data)=>{
        console.log(data.body);
      });
    }
```

My VueJS app runs on port `8080`, and my PHP runs on XAMPP on port `80`.
When I try to fetch something from my API I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Response {url: "http://localhost:80/gaming/api/game/1", ok: false, status: 0, statusText: "", headers: Headers, …}
```

What can I do?

Comment: check the requests(network) in the browser's developer tools, maybe you have a problem with [preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)

Comment: @Evhz I've checked the network tab and the request seems to appear there with the correct response. But the promise is failing in VueJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` to allow `CORS` on `php`.
good luck

Comment: what if is only vue app?

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable CORS? Use Developer tools to verify that your call is not failing due to CORS. Installing CORS extension in chrome and enabling CORS can help. Alternatively, if you have to run the application on localhost only, then add OPTIONS in your PHP application.

Comment: I don't think its a CORS issue, as the result is `404` and not something else.

Comment: Oddly enough - this was the problem.
Had to debug using a standard AJAX request with JS to get the `cross origin` error in the console.